# Не срабатывает фуннкция очистки onClear

Tags: javascript, функции

Привет, есть код, при нажатии на кнопку "Clear" должны очиститься все элемент в списке, что у меня не так?

```js
let tasks = [
    "Выучить JavaScript",
    "Выучить Angular 4",
    "Выучить React"
];
 
let ul = document.querySelector('.list-group');
let form = document.forms['addTodoItem'];
let addInput = form['todo'];
let clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clear-list');
 
 
 
function listTemplate(task) {
    //create tag li
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = task;
    li.className = 'list-group-item d-flex';
    //create tag i
    let i = document.createElement('i');
    i.className = 'fas fa-trash-alt ml-auto remove-list-item removeBtns';
    //append i to li
    li.appendChild(i);
    //return element i
    return li;
}
 
let removeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('removeBtns');
 
function generateList(tasksArray) {
    clearList();
 
    for ( let i = 0; i < tasksArray.length; i++){
        let liTemplate = listTemplate(tasksArray[i]);
        ul.appendChild(liTemplate);
    }
 
    setListeners();
}
 
function addTask(string) {
    if ( !string || typeof string !== 'string') return new Error('Не передана строка');
    if ( !string.length ) return new Error('Строка не должна быть пустой');
 
    tasks.unshift(string);
 
    generateList(tasks);
}
 
function clearList() {
    ul.innerHTML = '';
}
 
function editTask(task, updtask) {
 
    let currentTask = tasks.indexOf(task);
    tasks[currentTask] = updtask;
    generateList(tasks);
 
 
}
 
function deleteTask(task) {
    let currentTask = tasks.indexOf(task);
    console.log(currentTask, task.length, task);
 
    if( currentTask !== -1){
        tasks.splice(currentTask, 1);
        ul.children[currentTask].remove();
    } else {
        console.warn('Задача не обнаружена');
    }
}
 
function setListeners() {
 
    //set listeners at remove btns
    for ( let i = 0; i < removeBtns.length; i++){
        removeBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            let parent = this.closest('li');
            deleteTask(parent.textContent);
        });
    }
}
 
function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 
    if ( !addInput.value ){
        addInput.classList.add('is-invalid')
    } else {
        addInput.classList.remove('is-invslid');
        addTask(addInput.value);
        form.reset();
    }
    console.dir(addInput);
}
 
function onClear(e) {
    tasks = [];
    ul.innerHTML = '';
}
 
form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);
 
clearBtn.addEventListener('submit', onClear);
 
 
//Генерация списка при загрузке страницы
generateList(tasks);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<section class="todo-list-wrapper mt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                Add todo
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form name="addTodoItem">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="todo">Text</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Please enter some text.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Todo list
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush"></ul>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3 clear-list">Clear</button>
    </div>
</section>
 
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

почему на сабмит вешаете обработчик ? clearBtn - находится за формой

```
clearBtn.addEventListener('click', onClear);
```